# twisted support for diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

Tags: python, twisted

Does anyone know if/when diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 will be supported by twisted? I currently see the following list of supported key exchanges:
ecdh-sha2-nistp256, ecdh-sha2-nistp384, ecdh-sha2-nistp521, diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256, diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1, diffie-hellman-group14-sha1, diffie-hellman-group1-exchange-sha1

Currently using version 18.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search the Twisted issue tracker for a ticket for adding such a feature.

If you do not find such a ticket, file one.

If the ticket is up for review, review it.
If the ticket is not up for review, implement it and submit it for review.

If you are unable to review or implement such a feature, post on the mailing list about your interest in the feature and any incentives you may be able to offer to motivate someone else to do the work.

The feature will be included in the first Twisted release to take place after the feature implementation has been merged into master.